# How to read csv data from kaggle in pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pycharm

Hi there if anyone can answer this.
I am trying to read csv data from kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/stack-overflow-2018-developer-survey in pycharm and online jupyter notebook but I can not find a command how to read.
I know how to read data if it is in my computer but not know from the online web. I will so grateful if anyone can help me in that.

Answer (score 0):

From the page you linked to, you have a couple of options.

1. Create a notebook and the input files will be automatically included. Run the first cell that's generated for you and it will print out the paths to the input files. You can use Pandas `read_csv` in the notebook to load the data using those paths.
2. Expand the input folder in the Data pane (top right of the notebook), click on the file you want and look for the Download link at the top right of the data grid.